# Find records with more than 1 column value in SQL

Tags: sql

To simplify things here is my table structure:

**Table Name: OCRD**

```
CardCode       E_Mail          U_NoEmail
123            test@hi.com     Y
124            test@hi.com     N
125            other@hi.com    Y
126            mail@hi.com     N
```

The table contains a unique ID, an email address, and a third column (`U_NoEmail`) which shows a preference for the email to be `opted in` or not to emails. It is a bit counterintuitive and Y = Opted Out, `N = Opted In`.  The `U_NoEmail` column can also be `NULL`.

I am trying to use a single query against this table to return a count.  The count is the number of email addresses that have more than one value for `U_NoEmail` in the table. In other words, I'd like to find the total number of email addresses that are opted in AND out, which from a business perspective is not helpful.

I can't figure out how to do this.  For example, I can get this by email address with the following query:

```
SELECT E_Mail, COUNT(DISTINCT E_Mail) 
FROM OCRD
GROUP BY E_Mail
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT U_NoEMail) > 1
```

Which returns all the addresses with more than one value for `U_NoEmail`.  But I can't figure out how to get this as a single total.  If I try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT E_Mail, COUNT(DISTINCT E_Mail) 
FROM OCRD
GROUP BY E_Mail
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT U_NoEMail) > 1
) result
```

I get the error:
No column was specified for column 2 of 'result'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT E_Mail, COUNT(DISTINCT E_Mail) AS EmailCount
FROM OCRD
GROUP BY E_Mail
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT U_NoEMail) > 1
) result
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Knew I was missing something!

Answer (score 5):

Try this,You are supposed to give name for each column in sub query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT E_Mail, COUNT(DISTINCT E_Mail)  **as distEmail**
FROM OCRD
GROUP BY E_Mail
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT U_NoEMail) > 1
) result
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution also works fine, could only pick one answer.  Appreciate the help!